# Core data sharing between iPhone and Apple Watch apps

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, apple-watch

I need to share data stored using Core Data between my Apple Watch app and iPhone app. I found that I need to create a framework for the same from the follwing repo [Apple Watch and Core Data](https://github.com/aalittle/CoreDataWatchKit)

Also I've found the following code from Raywenderlich to share Core Data:

```
let kMyAppGroupName = "com.raywenderlich.mywatchapp.container"
var sharedContainerURL: NSURL? = NSFileManager.defaultManager().
 containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier(kMyAppGroupName)
 if let sharedContainerURL = sharedContainerURL {
 let storeURL = sharedContainerURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyCoreData.sqlite")
 var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = 
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel) coordinator?.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, 
configuration: nil,
URL: storeURL,
options: nil,
error: nil)
}
```

I've already done the iPhone part of the app using Core Data but I fail to share it with Apple Watch app. Can anyone suggest a way so that I can extend my current Core Data store to the apple watch app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the method `openParentApplication:reply:` to retrieve that information:

[Check Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:)